# Office Mobile not installed yet opening PDF files

Tags: ms-office

I have a Samsung A50 phone, stock Android which came with the device (from Comcast), everything up to date and not rooted. I have not registered for the Samsung Galaxy store or whatever is called, and therefore never installed anything from it.

I never installed Office Mobile on my phone, and looking at the list of installed apps in Google Play shows no Office Mobile.

Yet, starting today, attempting to open some (but not all!) PDF files (by tapping their name in the Document folder) opens them in Office Mobile rather than the "Google Drive PDF viewer" where they did open till the day before yesterday (I did not try yesterday).

There is not an option to force opening the files in "Google Drive PDF viewer". For a test, I installed the "Google PDF Viewer" (I wish they chose less similar and less confusing names). After that Android allows me to open the files with "Google PDF Viewer", but it fails with "Cannot display PDF (no file received)". After a reboot, the files were gone.

What may have happened? I can guess that the files corrupted and the "Google Drive PDF viewer" magically knew (and therefore was not proposing itself to open them), whereas the other two apps did.

Yet, why is there an app which I never installed and does not show up in the list of installed apps? Heck, if I search for it in Google Play, I even find it, and it shows me the option to install it!

Comment: I had something similar on my Sony XA2, but I only got a question if I want to open the PDF file in some Office app (I think it was the same app you are talking about). The dialog that popped up was not the default Android app selector, hence I was assuming that this was some built-in advertisement for a special app added by Sony. May you also got such a dialog and have clicked yes and therefore automatically installed it. Or it came include in an Android system update.

Answer (score 0):

1.When searching for apps. Tap the menu  hamburger, items on the right, then tap show system files etc.
It should be in there. From this you can go into the application information and clear everything especially "Defaults".
Or
2. However, you can try this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith

Or just simply install office and uninstall it after you have demonstrated step one.

Good luck